# strcmp always true

Tags: c++, strcmp

Why is the if statment always true?

```
char dot[] = ".";
char twoDots[] = "..";
cout << "d_name is " << ent->d_name << endl;
if(strcmp(ent->d_name, dot) || strcmp(ent->d_name, twoDots))
```

Am I using `strcmp` wrong?

Comment: Look at the return values section: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/

Comment: Short answer is yes but you may want to use `std::string` in C++ anyway ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`strcmp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) returns `0` when strings equal and a string cannot be both `"."` and `".."`. meaning one side of the `||` will always be non-zero and therefore the condition is always `true`.

To correct:

```
if(0 == strcmp(ent->d_name, dot) || 0 == strcmp(ent->d_name, twoDots))
```

An alternative would be to use `std::string` to store the dot variables and use `==`:

```
#include <string>

const std::string dot(".");
const std::string twoDots("..");

if (ent->d_name == dot || ent->d_name == twoDots)
```

Comment: I would prefer `!` instead of `0 ==`.

Answer (score 7):

`strcmp()` returns nonzero in case of a difference (and thus evaluates to `true`).

Also have a look at the docs (links below). Also have a look on [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) which provides an `operator==()` for tasks like this. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12013209/1025391) for the *how*.

---

> Returns an integral value indicating the relationship between the strings:
>   A zero value indicates that both strings are equal.
>   A value greater than zero indicates that the first character that does not match has a greater value in str1 than in str2; And a value less than zero indicates the opposite.

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/

---

> The return value for each of these functions indicates the lexicographic relation of string1 to string2.

```
Value   Relationship of string1 to string2

 < 0    string1 less than string2
   0    string1 identical to string2
 > 0    string1 greater than string2
```

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0z9k731%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: How come `strcmp` works on `std::string` when it expects `char *`?

Comment: @Celeritas `strcmp` doesn't work on `std::string` (unless you order the corresponding zero-terminated [C-string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)). To test for equivalence you'd simply use [`s1 == s2`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/operators/).

Answer (score 3):

`strcmp` returns -1, 0, or 1 if the strings are lexicographically prior, equal, or later respectively.

To check whether strings are *equal*, use `strcmp(s1, s2) == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `strcmp` returns `0` when equal and `1 or -1` when different, at least one of the two strcmp is returning `1 or -1`, the `||` will return true when any condition is something different of `0`, you should do this...

```
if(strcmp(ent->d_name, dot) == 0 || strcmp(ent->d_name, twoDots) == 0)
```

I added `== 0` after every strcmp

Answer (score 0):

strcmp by itself does not return a boolean. Instead, it returns an int. 0 if match, other if no match. So this should help:

```
if(0 == strcmp(d_name, dot) || 0 == strcmp(d_name, twoDots)) {
    // Other code here
}
```